# What does opsmenu do?

Tags: sas

I noticed that a user on one of the SAS servers I use at work was running the following SAS related process:

```
/opt/apps/sas91/SAS_9.1/SASProfiles/Menus/opsmenu
```

Does anyone know what this does? I can't find any mention of it on Google, this site, the SAS support website, or any of the docs I've looked at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OPSMENU is used for the administration of SAS user profiles - specifically it refers to the Options Menu.  This command would typically be used to perform admin tasks such as creating a new user profile.  OPSMENU is an outdated process though, so it's not used in more recent versions of SAS (this is probably why you can't find any info on it).

This info comes directly from a SAS rep I spoke with earlier today.

Comment: Could you provide a specific example of why / how someone would end up running this process?

Comment: One example would be if you were an admin creating a new user profile.